# Any OpengGL Shader Spelling Checker?

Tags: opengl, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I haven't found a tool for checking text spelling on OnpenGL shader for eclipse or another.
Dealing with spelling errors on text based shaders like:

```
    protected String vertexShaderCode =
// This matrix member variable provides a hook to manipulate
// the coordinates of the objects that use this vertex shader
"uniform   mat4 uMVPMatrix; \n" + "attribute vec3 vPosition;  \n"
        + "void main(){               \n" +
        // the matrix must be included as a modifier of gl_Position
        " gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vec4(vPosition, 1.0); \n" + "}  \n";
```

is a very time consuming task.

So, i wonder if somebody knows some kind of tool that helps with that.

Comment: What do you mean by check the spelling? Are you talking about syntax highlighting or full syntactical analysis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Shader Designer](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/tools/ShaderDesigner/) from Typhoon Labs is a full-featured GLSL IDE. For quick checks/editing, I have also used [this](http://www.leadwerks.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=5414) user defined language for Notepad++.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should read your shader in as a text file. Then you can use your favorite word processor when editing your shader. If your talking plain spell checking. In which case A LOT of things will appear misspelled unless you add every word you allow (uMVPMatrix is not included in a standard dictionary).

Or if you want it to recognized initialized and non initialized variables you'd be better of writing a script which can find all initialized variables and contains a list of valid function names from OpenGL. Then checks to see if it can find anything it doesn't know from the two lists.

Answer (score 0):

You say you were using Eclipse? What did you mean by other? If you meant another editor then for Visual Studio NShader is quite useful. While it doesn't provide auto-complete it does colour syntax to help spot problems.